# PySMI get oid name from MIB

Tags: oid

Is there a way to retrieve the OID name from a MIB file. It extracts the OID, but not the OID name. I am using the latest version of PySMI:

I expected this to be in the generated JSON file, but it is not there.

An example is: enterprises.eltek.eNexus.powerSystem.powerSystemSite.0